# Testing google analytics

Tags: mobile, google-analytics

I am new to google analytics and mobile testing and got a task of testing google analytics on one of our in-house application. could you guys please help me by understanding that how can I proceed doing so. I have no idea about google analytics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform the actions that you are actually tracking and check if a corresponding entry is recorded in the analytics database.

Answer (score -1):

As a starting point, first check if your UA tracking ID is implemented. Secondly, make some interaction with you mobile application and check if the data is available in Google Analytics (e.g. real time report).